# Permission denied while doing mandatory mount

Tags: centos, mount

I was trying to do mandatory lock on a file before that I was doing mandatory mount but I was getting error

```
[root@magneto /]# sudo mount -t tmpfs -o mand,size=1m tmpfs ./hpdir
mount: /hpdir: permission denied.
```

Comment: Try with absolute path of mountpoint

Comment: nope did not work

Comment: Try mounting to another directory as a test, and double check that hpdir actually is a directory, and not a file or socket or something.

Comment: mounting to another directory did not work

Comment: Anything in `dmesg`?

Comment: `read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Er... in your example command, you're already root, but you prefixed the command with "sudo"?  Does it make any difference if you invoke the mount command without sudo?

Comment: In some distributions only root can run `dmesg`. You'll get your error message if a non-privileged account tries it.